# rvest cannot find node with xpath

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

This is the website I scapre
[ppp projects](http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/ppp/projectLivrary/toPPPList.do)

I want to use xpath to select the node like below
[image]

The xpath I get by use inspect element is "//*[@id="pppListUl"]/li[1](http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/ppp/projectLivrary/toPPPList.do)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdIUl.png)/span[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdIUl.png)/span"

My scrpits are like below:

```
a <- html("http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/ppp/projectLivrary/toPPPList.do")
b <- html_nodes(a, xpath = '//*[@id="pppListUl"]/li[1]/div[2]/span[2]/span')
b
```

Then I got the result

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Then I check the page source, I didn't even find anything about the project I selected.

I was wondering why I cannot find it in the page source, and in turn, how can I get the node by rvest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes an XHR request for the content. Just work with that data (it's pretty clean):

```
library(httr)

POST('http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/ppp/projectLivrary/getPPPList.do?tokenid=null',
     encode="form",
     body=list(queryPage=1,
               distStr="",
               induStr="",
               investStr="",
               projName="",
               sortby="",
               orderby="",
               stageArr="")) -> res

content(res, as="text") %>% 
  jsonlite::fromJSON(flatten=TRUE) %>% 
  dplyr::glimpse()
```

(StackOverflow isn't advanced enough to let me post the output of that as it thinks it's spam).

It's a 4 element list with fields `totalCount`, `list` (which has the actual data), `currentPage` and `totalPage`.

It looks like you can change the `queryPage` form variable to iterate through the pages to get the whole list/database, something like:

```
library(httr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

get_page <- function(page_num=1, .pb=NULL) {

  if (!is.null(.pb)) pb$tick()$print()

  POST('http://www.cpppc.org:8082/efmisweb/ppp/projectLivrary/getPPPList.do?tokenid=null',
       encode="form",
       body=list(queryPage=page_num,
                 distStr="",
                 induStr="",
                 investStr="",
                 projName="",
                 sortby="",
                 orderby="",
                 stageArr="")) -> res

  content(res, as="text") %>% 
    jsonlite::fromJSON(flatten=TRUE) -> dat

  dat$list

}

n <- 5 # change this to the value in `totalPage`

pb <- progress_estimated(n)
df <- map_df(1:n, get_page, pb)
```